# Не правильная работа процедуры Oracle11R2

Tags: oracle

Написал процедуру на удаление полей но она ничего не делает:

```
Create or replace procedure delete_test
Is
Begin
    Delete from tab.test1 t1
    Where t1.id not in (select t2.id from tab.test2 t2);
End;
```

Выполняется без ошибок но и не удаляет. `Not in` использовал потому как полей больше.

Что я не так сделал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны два варианта (возможно, оба сразу):

1. Вы забыли сделать `commit`. Решение - поставить `commit` в конце блока либо выполнить его кнопочкой из IDE (если пользуетесь IDE)
2. Условие в `where` написано таким образом, что удаляется 0 строк. Проверьте, запрос

   ```
   select *  from tab.test1 t1 
   Where t1.id not in (select t2.id from tab.test2 t2)
   ```

   должен выдавать строки, которые должны удаляться. Если запрос возвращает 0 строк, значит, вам просто нечего удалять.

Comment: Дело в том что через 'Select' выбирает без проблем. Тоесть есть что удалять. 'Commit' не исправил проблему

Comment: Мистика какая-то. Вы как код запускаете? Из IDE? Попробуйте добавить после `DELETE ...` (но **до** коммита) строку `dbms_output.put_line('rows deleted: ' || sql%rowcount);`. Что выдает?

Comment: А, еще вариант: вы открыли сессию 1, вставили строки, **не закоммитили** их, потом открыли сессию 2, сделали там `delete` (который ничего не удалил, потому что сессия 2 не видит строки, незакоммиченные в сессии 1), а проверяете есть что удалять или нет опять в сессии 1 (и там есть что удалять, потому что строки вставлены).

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь, процедура выполнилась за 90 сек )) Тут чисто моя невнимательность, скомпилировал а запустить забыл. Единственное не понятно почему dbms_output ничего не вывел (((((

Comment: Почему dbms_output ничего не вывел, тоже зависит от способа запуска. Если из SQLPlus, то надо сначала выполнить команду `set serveroutput on`, если из IDE - то включать в настройках IDE.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.